# How to run command line command as administrator via java

Tags: java, windows, command-line, dhcp, runas

I'm currently trying to set a static DNS as part of a program I am building. The only logical way I can find to do it however is to use command lines in the background.

```
String auto = "cmd.exe /c start runas.exe /user:administrator netsh interface ip set dns \"Local Area Connection\" dhcp";

 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(auto)
```

I keep trying this and the only thing i get is the directory of commands runas accepts. Is there a way to enable to dhcp with this runas method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put quote marks around the command you want `runas` to run.

Something like this should work:

```
auto = "cmd /c [...] \"netsh interface ip set dns \\\"Local Area Connection\\\" dhcp\"";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That problem was driving me crazy